# C# Sortedset .remove funstions

Tags: c#

I am coding a software in c# and i am using the sortedset generic collection to store a class member called Message.
The sortedset uses a custom compare functions.

Every new member have a diffrrent ID .

I am using the sortedset.remove function to remove a message after it printed (by checking the ID).

I have a probleom that in some computers the .remove functions starting by checking the second element (index 1) and than in some cases the function dont check the first element (index 0) and dont delete it (if this is the desired element to remove).

This probleom occures only in some computers, in other computers the .remove functione start by checking the first element (index 0) and dont missing an elements.

I cant add any code becuse the software is in a non-internet computer.

Thank you very much, yakir.

Comment: Note the section of the [tagging help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) entitled _"Should I use tags in titles?"_.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. _Note that you should do this even if the software is on a non-internet computer - you will need to create the [mcve] on an internet computer._